# Android proguard removes all classes in the root jar

Tags: android, android-studio, proguard, android-proguard, shrink

I have an Android project which contains external libraries. One of the library  (.jar) contains classes in the root package. Somehow Android proguard removes all these classes which makes the app fails to run.

I've searched around and I think it is related to this issue https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=196905 where all classes in the root is neglected.

Anyone knows how can I run the proguard without using the Android proguard so that all root classes is kept?

Comment: Did u try keeping -libraryjars libs in proguard rules?

Comment: Yes..I did. The classes in root are still removed when I use -libraryjars.

Comment: It gets fixed once I use Android gradle plugin  -> com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2